# Unable to overwrite the session variable in express

Tags: ajax, node.js, session, express-session

I am using a ajax call to set a session variable, like:

```
 $.ajax({
           url: "url", -- a call to node layer
           type: 'GET',
           success: function (response) {


           }

       });
```

In node layer , i am doing an API call to set the new session value , like:

```
getxxx:function (req, res){

        var options = {};
        var self=this;
        options.headers = {};
        options.headers['Authorization'] = req.session.Authorization;
        options.headers['loginId'] = req.session.userName;
        var data={};       

        proxyAPI.getData(common.getEndpointURL("XXX", req.session.userName), {}, options, function(err, response, statusCode){
            data.xxx = response;            
            if(data.xxx && data.xxx.count) {
                req.session.count = data.xxx.count;
                req.session.save();

            }
        });   

    },
```

My App.js looks like this:

```
app.use(sessionexpress({
        secret: 'secretKey',
        cookie: {
            maxAge: config.timeout,            
            secure: config.sslEnabled
        },
        rolling: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        resave: true,
        store: new MemcachedStore({
            hosts: [config.sessionStore.uri],
            secret: config.sessionStore.secret 
        })
    }));
```

Scenario:
In the call back function, I need to set the updated value from the API layer to the session variable.
Purpose is to use the value (req.session.count) in another page.

The problem is :
When i try to access the req.session.count variable in another page , the value doesn't show the updated value instead shows the value assigned at app startup.

What Am I doing wrong in this?

Note:
If i change the session variable without any API calls , like this :

```
req.session.count = 100;
req.session.save();
```

I am able to get the new session value (i.e 100) in other pages !

Comment: About to go to sleep but at a glance it looks like `getxxx` returns before `proxyAPI.getData` ever returns. You'd want `function (req, res, next)` as you handler and then call `next` in the `proxyAPI.getData` callback.

Comment: @Christopher Tarquini : Thanks for your reply ! But i couldn't understand the concept. Can you elaborate please.

Comment: Basically this: https://gist.github.com/ilsken/f9908553b1299f66c7967e734b92aed8

Comment: I tried this. But still the same ..  One more point to note here , this is an ajax call just to overwrite the session value. After this, when i navigate to some other page in UI and when i investigate the session value in the respective handler, the value is not updated.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the API calls and use Ajax? How are you calling it via Ajax (XMLHttpRequest, fetch, etc)? I would double check cookies are being sent with your ajax request

Comment: From UI to node i am using ajax which is XMLHttpRequest. If i remove the API call in node and just try updating the session variable without any callback , it is working fine. But i need the callback to get the count from the database and set to the session variable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138046/discussion-between-user883822-and-christopher-tarquini).

Comment: Thanks @Christopher Tarquini your solution worked for me.In the first function stack I did a API call on success response did a 'next()' and called the next function in the middleware layer to send AJAX response to the UI.